# How to pass validation errors ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a custom controller (I'm using it as a patch for issue [ActiveAdmin not saving has_many nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979595/activeadmin-not-saving-has-many-nested-object))

the problem I need to fix is the validation errors and keeping the form data. Before I did the custom controller, the errors would pop up underneath the input field like so

[image: Screnshot]

but now they do not show up. Please help! Thanks :)

**ActiveAdmin.register**

```
controller do
    def create
        @section = AbqCouncilors::Councilor.create!(permitted_params[:abq_councilors_councilor].as_json)
        redirect_to admin_abq_councilor_path, notice: "Councilor was successfully created!"         
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work with the below change. 
**Important** Must have `@resource` as the instance variable. Would not work with any other

```
controller do
    def create
        @resource = AbqCouncilors::Councilor.new(permitted_params[:abq_councilors_councilor].as_json)
        if @resource.save
            flash[:notice] = "Councilor was successfully created!"
            redirect_to admin_abq_councilor_path(@resource.id)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Your form is missing or has incomplete fields. Please review your entry below."
            render action: 'new'
        end
    end
end
```